# Ionic view name not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that I'm trying to build some views for. However, for some reason when I create a unique `view-name` name, my view doesn't work and it redirects to `#/tab/home`. The view I'm trying to create is called `login`, it should be accessed by going to `#/tab/login`.

Here's my full `app.js` file.

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ui.rCalendar'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.feed', {
    url: '/feed',
    views: {
      'tab-feed': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-feed.html',
        controller: 'FeedCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'tab-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.chat-detail', {
    url: '/chats/:chatId',
    views: {
      'tab-chats': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
        controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events',
    views: {
      'tab-events': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.cart', {
    url: '/cart',
    views: {
      'tab-cart': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-cart.html',
        controller: 'CartCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/login');

});
```

I've got a file called `tab-login.html`. When I change the `view-name` from `tab-login` to anything else that already exists like `tab-feed`, when I go to `#/tab/login` it works fine. So it works when it looks like this:

```
.state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'tab-feed': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

It works just fine...which makes no sense to me. What am I doing wrong? And why is it redirecting to `home` when I have it set to default to `login`?

Comment: have you checked if the fallback may be the cause for this?
try remove 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/login'); 
for a second

Comment: I've removed the line, then when i go to `http://192.168.191.128:8100/#/tab/login` it still redirects to `home`

Comment: Do a console log in your login controller to see if it gets instantiated.

Comment: I put a log in my login controller and my home controller, when I go to /login, it redirects to /home and the home controller log is the one that gets fired off

Comment: My next suggestion is to add a .run function with a rootscope on listener for the state change events. Its function should be a state protector with the to, from, etc. values. Then you can log inside that listener and see what states and params are actually occurring in the routing process.

Comment: I'm pretty new to ionic (working with it for a day), what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Make sure in your templates/tabs.html you have a view with the name `tab-login`